# Run python script as upstart service with specific python version

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, centos, upstart

I'm working on setting up an upstart service for a python script on my centOs server. Though the script needs python 2.7 to be working. But the default python version on the server is 2.6 and I do not want to change it as I'm afraid other scripts will fail then.

I have installed python 2.7 and tested it and it works perfectly fine with my script. Though I am wondering of how I should write the .conf file to make the file execute with python 2.7. Because right now I get a "Job failed to start" message. And I beleive it might be because it's using 2.6 when executing the script.

This is my current conf file (with changed directory and file names though):

```
description "MY SCRIPT DESCRIPTION"
author "MY NAME"

start on runlevel [234]
stop on runlevel [0156]

chdir /home/aUser/scriptLocation
exec /home/aUser/scriptLocation/theScript.py
respawn
```

Comment: Your first paragraph says that you _do_ want to use 2.7 but end up running under 2.6. Your second paragraph implies that you _don't_ want to use 2.7, and think "it might be because it's using 2.7 when executing the script" that the job fails to start. I'm guessing it's the former, not the latter, but you should edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: Also, have you put a `#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7` or similar at the top of your `theScript.py`, or `#!/usr/bin/python`? Because if it's the latter, that's why you're having this problem. I don't know how you're deploying the script, but various things (including `setuptools` ) know how to automatically update the shebang as part of installation/deployment, so just fixing your deployment process might be the right solution here.

Comment: Sorry for my typo. I want to use 2.7 but I think it's using 2.6. So I've changed that. I think Daniel's answer will work though (if I just use 2.7 instead of 2.6). But I'll have to wit until tomorrow to try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just call the Python executable directly and pass the script as a parameter, rather than calling the script itself.

```
exec /path/to/my/python2.6 /home/aUser/scriptLocation/theScript.py
```

Comment: I think he's looking to use 2.7, not 2.6 here (although the question is a little unclear), but otherwise, spot on.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that by tomorrow morning. And abarnert is right regarding the versions. It's my bad though as I made a typo in the question so that it became rather unclear. But I'll try your method tomorrow and then mark your comment as an answer if it works.